# Сompiler bug? Variable assumed unchanged

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-bug

Visual Studio version: **17.7.1 (MSVC 19.37.32822)**
Freshly created project with default settings and compiler flags.

Minimal reproducible example:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

__declspec(noinline) void test2(char** data)
{
    // After moving the pointer:
    // data_1 now points to data[1] = 1
    // data_0 now points to data[0] = 2
    *data += 1;
}

__declspec(noinline) void test(char* data_1)
{
    char* data_0 = data_1;
    test2(&data_1);
    int len = (int)(data_1 - data_0);

    if (*data_1 & 1)
    {
        if (*data_0 & 2)
            printf("good\n");
     }
}

int main()
{
    char data[2];
    data[0] = 2;
    data[1] = 1;
    test(data);
    return 0;
}
```

**No line "good" is printed in Release| x64 configuration.**
Debug or Release | x86 produce expected result.

I did some experimenting and looked through resulting assembly in order to reduce the original code to this MRE.
The root cause of the issue seem to be the compiler's assumption that `data1` remains unchanged in `test2()`. Thus, the line `data_0 = data_1` can be omitted and `data_1` can be used instead of `data_0` in the expression `(*data_0 & 2)`.
Each line is necessary, including the casting of `(data_1 - data_0)` to int, which probably explains the lack of bug reproduction in the x86 build.

### Update 1

Problem only occurs in the x64 Release build. Disabling optimizations by changing /O2 to /Od or using `#pragma optimize("", off)` "fixes" the problem.

Reproducibility by VS version breakdown:

- 17.7.1 - problem
- 17.7.2 - problem
- ???
- 17.7.6 - no problem
- 17.8 preview 7 - no problem

It's possible that the problem has already been fixed or the conditions for its reproduction have changed.

### Update 2

One of the MSVC developers confirmed this problem in a private conversation, I've made this issue to track progress: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Compiler-optimization-bug-in-VS-2022/10512534

Comment: You aren’t changing the data in test2. You are incrementing the pointer

Comment: "You aren’t changing the data in test2. You are incrementing the pointer" -- that's intended. After moving the pointer, `data_1` now points to `data[1] = 1`, whereas `data_0` points to `data[0] = 2`

Comment: For previous commenters, please explain the difference between Debug and Release builds, before jumping to conclusions.

Comment: The primary difference between Debug and Release builds is that a Debug build has symbols.  A Debug build may also have functionality that is removed from a Release build, such as logging.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews They were asked to explain the difference in behavior between debug and release builds of **that particular piece of code**

Comment: I don't see any source of UB. The behavior seems to me should be well defined.

Comment: What happens if you disable the optimization s?

Comment: @zdf There is no problem with optimization turned off. I've updated the question with additional information.

Comment: If you add `else` statements (which display unique strings), do you find out which `if` condition failed or is it a Heisenbug?

Comment: @BenVoigt Inner condition is failing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can confirm that the same behaviour is present here. In addition any attempt to printf values to check the else (fail) conditions results in correct behaviour. Optimiser has been too aggressive. It only fetches *data_1 and applies both tests to it (assuming that data_1==data_0 which of course isn't true).

Any alteration to print out debugging values seems to result in correct behaviour. I added printf("bad data_0") instead to the inner else clause and predictably that got printed out. I prefer to have all paths annotated.

FWIW Intel compiler 2023 runs it fine and prints "good".

Smoking gun - MSC compiler bug excessively aggressive optimisation fails to load *data_0 and applies both tests to *data_1. Disassembly is here (with slight additions which don't affect errant behaviour) :

--- C:\Users\Martin\source\repos\Toy_bug1\Toy_bug1.cpp ------------------------

```
// After moving the pointer:
// data_1 now points to data[1] = 1
// data_0 now points to data[0] = 2
*data += 1;
00007FF6D10B1070  inc         qword ptr [rcx]  
}
00007FF6D10B1073  ret  
[snip]
__declspec(noinline) void test(char* data_1)
{
00007FF6D10B1080  mov         qword ptr [rsp+8],rcx  
00007FF6D10B1085  sub         rsp,28h  
char* data_0 = data_1;
test2(&data_1);
00007FF6D10B1089  lea         rcx,[data_1]  
00007FF6D10B108E  call        test2 (07FF6D10B1070h)  
int len = (int)(data_1 - data_0);

if (*data_1 & 1)
00007FF6D10B1093  mov         rax,qword ptr [data_1]  
00007FF6D10B1098  movzx       ecx,byte ptr [rax]  
00007FF6D10B109B  test        cl,1  
00007FF6D10B109E  je          test+3Eh (07FF6D10B10BEh)  
{
    if (*data_0 & 2)
00007FF6D10B10A0  test        cl,2  // this test is incorrect!
        printf("good\n");
    else
        printf("bad d0");
}
00007FF6D10B10A3  lea         rax,[string "bad d0" (07FF6D10B2258h)]  
00007FF6D10B10AA  lea         rcx,[string "good\n" (07FF6D10B2250h)]  
00007FF6D10B10B1  cmove       rcx,rax  
}
```

I remain a little mystified about the significance of the crucial line in the MRE which is optimised out of existence but is essential for the fault to show!
Namely:

int len = (int)(data_1 - data_0);

Without this line present the MSC compiler gets it right in x64 release. Here is the disassembly of the correct code generated in that case:

```
//    int len = (int)(data_1 - data_0);

if (*data_1 & 1)
00007FF6D6D11096  mov         rax,qword ptr [data_1]  
00007FF6D6D1109B  test        byte ptr [rax],1  
00007FF6D6D1109E  je          test+3Eh (07FF6D6D110BEh)  
{
     if (*data_0 & 2)
00007FF6D6D110A0  test        byte ptr [rdx],2  
// rax  is data_1
// rdx  is data_0
```

Moral of story is beware of doing things that confuse optimising compilers!

Comment: The line `int len = (int)(data_1 - data_0);` came from the original code, where len is actually used later. So I'm not trying to confuse compiler on purpose :)

Comment: The original code comes from mysql (specifically mariadb): https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/11.3/storage/myisam/mi_delete.c#L839C13-L839C13 here, lines 797, 802, 824, 839 are relevant. See variables `start` and `keypos`.

Comment: It is curious that a line that gets optimised into oblivion can have such annoying side effects. I actually had in mind altering test2 to be a function which accepts a pointer and returns its value after being incremented. I think that will be sufficient to make the code reliable with even the most bone headed aggressive optimiser. Allowing it to inline might also fix the pointer modified visibility problem.  You can run the Intel compiler from inside the MSVC shell and switch between them. I find it helpful. Intel is way better at vectorising numeric code and more standards compliant.

Comment: Mark this as an answer, since you actually bothered to investigate the problem instead of claiming it to be my mistake. Issue is confirmed and is being fixed by the MSVC team.

Comment: It's just a bug. Compilers are also programs afterall. I don't think it makes sense to write code "defensively" or bloat it with some extra "insisting" to fight compiler. Bug will be fixed, that's all.

Comment: But yes, we also were surprised by how the line that gets optimized away still is necessary to trigger the problem.

Comment: @codeguard I disagree. Having a void routine that mutilates a pointer handed to it is deliberate obfuscation of the worst possible sort. It should provide the modified pointer back to the caller as a return value - then the code would be bullet proof against compiler quirks. Just because something is allowed and well defined valid C doesn't mean you should do it! Readability and avoiding any ambiguity is important too.

Comment: Remember that this is minimal repro. In original mariadb code, function is not void and code is not artificial at all.